# Add Alpha to Shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have the following shader,

I'm trying to add an alpha to the white, however all attempts have proven to be difficult.

This is the project from which I obtained the shader for reference - [github](https://github.com/mattatz/unity-cellular-automaton-based-ink-simulation)

I think it has to do with one of the passes overwriting.

```
Shader "Suibokuga/Suibokuga" {

    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Water Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Alpha ("Transfer/Diffusion coefficient for water particles", Range(0.01, 1.5)) = 1.0
        _Evaporation ("a unit quantity of water for evaporation", Range(0.0001, 0.005)) = 0.00015

        _PaperTex ("Paper Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

        _Brush ("brush", Vector) = (-1, -1, -1, -1)
        _Prev ("previous brush position", Vector) = (-1, -1, -1, -1)
    }

    CGINCLUDE

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"
    #pragma target 3.0

    /*
     * r : water particles
     * b : capacities of water 
     * a : the heights of the bottoms
     */
    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

    float _Alpha;
    float _Evaporation;

    sampler2D _PaperTex;

    float2 _Prev;
    float3 _Brush; // x,y : position, z : size

    struct appdata {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    struct v2f {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f vert (appdata IN) {
        v2f OUT;
        OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
        OUT.uv = IN.uv;
        return OUT;
    }

    void sample (float2 uv, out float4 o, out float4 l, out float4 t, out float4 r, out float4 b) {
        float2 texel = _MainTex_TexelSize.xy;
        o = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
        l = tex2D(_MainTex, uv + float2(-texel.x,        0));
        t = tex2D(_MainTex, uv + float2(       0, -texel.y));
        r = tex2D(_MainTex, uv + float2( texel.x,        0));
        b = tex2D(_MainTex, uv + float2(       0,  texel.y));
    }

    float waterDelta (float4 k, float4 o) {
        float ld = (k.w + k.x) - (o.w + o.x); // level difference 
        float transfer = (k.w + k.x) - max(o.w, k.w + k.z); // transferable water particles
        return max(
            0.0,
            0.25 * _Alpha * min(ld, transfer)
        );
    }

    float waterFlow (float2 uv) {
        float4 o, l, t, r, b;
        sample(uv, o, l, t, r, b);

        float nw = o.r;
        nw += (waterDelta(l, o) - waterDelta(o, l));
        nw += (waterDelta(t, o) - waterDelta(o, t));
        nw += (waterDelta(r, o) - waterDelta(o, r));
        nw += (waterDelta(b, o) - waterDelta(o, b));
        return max(nw, 0);
    }

    float evaporation (float wo) {
        return max(wo - _Evaporation, 0.0);
    }

    float brush (float2 uv) {
        const int count = 10;

        float2 dir = _Brush.xy - _Prev.xy;
        float l = length(dir);
        if(l <= 0) {
            float d = length(uv - _Brush.xy);
            return smoothstep(0.0, _Brush.z, _Brush.z - d);
        }

        float ld = l / count;
        float2 norm = normalize(dir);
        float md = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            float2 p = _Prev.xy + norm * ld * i;
            float d = length(uv - p);
            if(d < md) {
                md = d;
            }
        }
        return smoothstep(0.0, _Brush.z, _Brush.z - md);

        // float d = length(uv - _Brush.xy);
        // return smoothstep(0.0, _Brush.z, _Brush.z - d);
    }

    ENDCG

    SubShader {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment init

            float4 init (v2f IN) : SV_Target {
                float4 paper = tex2D(_PaperTex, IN.uv);
                return float4(
                    0,
                    0,
                    paper.r,
                    paper.r
                );
            }

            ENDCG
        }

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment waterUpdate

            float4 waterUpdate (v2f IN) : SV_Target {
                float4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv);
                col.x = evaporation(waterFlow(IN.uv));

                float dw = brush(IN.uv);
                // if(dw > 0) {
                    col.x = min(col.x + brush(IN.uv), 1.0);
                // }

                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment visualize

            float4 visualize (v2f IN) : SV_Target {
                float4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv);
                return float4(1.0 - col.xxx, 1.0);
            }

            ENDCG
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to miss a blending step.

Try adding this line to the end of the last pass

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

Check [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html) to learn about alpha blending for Unity shaders.
The line I attached is for standard transparency, you might want to try different blending options.